# Routes not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am learning how to use React and React Router by making a personalized version of the Single Page Application example found here [SPA App](https://www.kirupa.com/react/creating_single_page_app_react_using_react_router.htm)

The one part I've changed based on errors I have received is that I wrapped the routing section in `<routes> </routes>` tags.

```
import { Route, NavLink, HashRouter, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Kurt from "./Kurt";
import Huff from "./Huff";
import Poe from "./Poe";

class Main extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <HashRouter>
        <div>
          <h1>My Favorite Authors</h1>
          <ul className='header'>
            <li>
              <NavLink exact="true" to='/'>Kurt Vonnegut</NavLink>
            </li>
            <li>
              <NavLink to='/Huff'>Tanya Huff</NavLink>
            </li>
            <li>
              <NavLink to='/Poe'>Edgar Allan Poe</NavLink>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <div className='content'>
            <Routes>
              <Route exact="true" path='/' element={Kurt} />
              <Route path='/Huff' element={Huff} />
              <Route path='/Poe' element={Poe} />
            </Routes>
          </div>
        </div>
      </HashRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

My menu is rendering, but none of the content for the components is showing up.  I don't understand why it isn't showing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`element`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#type-declaration) prop expects a ReactNode not a Component.

So try

```
<Route exact="true" path='/' element={<Kurt />} />
<Route path='/Huff' element={<Huff />} />
<Route path='/Poe' element={<Poe />} />
```

Comment: This was exactly the issue.  Has this always been the syntax, or is this something that I may have missed by learning an older version of React?